# Why this column space of a matrix only has dimension 2?

Tags: matrices

So I know that we determine the dimension of the column space of matrix by choosing the linear independent columns.

But I read that the matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$$

has dimension 2... Shouldn't it has dimension 3? Because the only linear dependent vectors are (1,0,0) and (2,0,0) but do we count them as 1 vector or do we simply ignore them (and do the answer 2 is right). Thanks!

Comment: If you choose three columns, then the last row would be zero. So how can they be independent?

Comment: Performing column elimination on the matrix will systematically zero out columns that are linear combinations of others. The reduced matrix has the same column space as the original, which you can then find by inspection. That’s in general a lot more reliable than trying to eyeball the original matrix to find linear dependence among its columns.

Answer (score 2):

We only count linearly independent column vectors.  Let $A_n$ be the $n^{th}$ column.
$A_1$ and $A_3$ are linearly independent.
$A_2=2A_1$ and
$A_4=A_1+A_3$
Then the maximal linearly independent subset has 2 members.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
(2,0,0)^T=2(1,0,0)^T 
$$
and
$$
(2,1,0)^T=(1,0,0)^T+(1,1,0)^T
$$

Answer (score 0):

In matrix form
$$A=\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0},$$ 
we can see that the second column is the double of the first, but also the sum of the first and the third give the fourth.

So, on two of the columns (the 1st and the 3rd) all others depend.